# Why does my state not change or work the first time I click submit in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-state

When you click submit, it says successful when it should fail because the fields are empty. After the first click, it works perfectly.

The submit button jumps into the handleSubmit function and it works perfectly after the first click. Not sure if I need something else to make sure it works the first time?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";



import SuccessAlert from '../Components/SuccessAlert'
import { Alert, AlertTitle } from '@material-ui/lab';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';

const useStyles = theme => ({
  paper: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'left',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    maxWidth: "200px"
  },
  root: {
    overFlowY: "scroll",
    marginTop: "8%",
    marginRight: "20px"
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: "20px",
    position: "absolute",
    left: "50px",
    marginRight: "50px"
  },
});


export class Connect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: "", email: "", message: ""};
    this.state = { showAlert: false };
    this.state = { emptyName: false, emptyEmail: false, emptyMessage: false };
    this.state = { helpName: "", helpEmail: "", helpMessage: "" };
  }


  handleSumbit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      message: this.state.message,
    };

    let errorCounter = 0;

    if (this.state.name == "")
    {
      this.setState({ emptyName: true, helpName: "Field must not be empty"})
      errorCounter = errorCounter + 1
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ emptyName: false, helpName: ""})
    }

    if (this.state.email == "")
    {
      this.setState({ emptyEmail: true, helpEmail: "Field must not be empty"})
      errorCounter = errorCounter + 1
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ emptyEmail: false, helpEmail: ""})
    }

    if (this.state.message == "")
    {
      this.setState({ emptyMessage: true, helpMessage: "Field must not be empty"})
      errorCounter = errorCounter + 1
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ emptyMessage: false, helpMessage: ""})
    }

    if (errorCounter != 0)
    {
      return false;
    }

    this.setState({ emptyMessage: false, emptyEmail: false, emptyName: false})
    this.setState({ showAlert: true });
    this.setState({ name: "", email: "", message: "" });

    //this.props.sendMessage(formData);

    setTimeout(function(){ this.setState({ showAlert: false }) }.bind(this), 5000);
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {

    const SubmitButton = (props) => {
      return <Route render={props => <Redirect to="/home" />}/>
    }

    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (

      <div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.title}>
        <h1>Connect with me</h1>

      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5" style={{maxWidth: "400px"}}>
          Say Hi! If you want to collaborate on something, or just want to connect with me, send me a message below.
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            error={this.state.emptyName}
            helperText={this.state.helpName}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="name"
            label="Name"
            type="name"
            id="name"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            style={{maxWidth: "500px"}}
          />

          <TextField
            error={this.state.emptyEmail}
            helperText={this.state.helpEmail}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            style={{maxWidth: "500px"}}
          />

          <TextField
            error={this.state.emptyMessage}
            helperText={this.state.helpMessage}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="message"
            label="Message"
            rows="4"
            name="message"
            value={this.state.message}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            autoComplete="none"
            autoFocus
            multiline
          />

          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
            onClick={this.handleSumbit}
          >
            Send Message
          </Button>

        </form>
        {this.state.showAlert ? (
                <SuccessAlert/>
              ) : null}
      </div>


    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}





export default withStyles(useStyles)(Connect);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do `this.state` in the constructor, the previous one is overriden.

```
   this.state = { name: "", email: "", message: ""};
    this.state = { showAlert: false };
    this.state = { emptyName: false, emptyEmail: false, emptyMessage: false };
    this.state = { helpName: "", helpEmail: "", helpMessage: "" };
```

Try

```
this.state = { 
        name: "", email: "", message: "", 
        showAlert: false, emptyName: false, 
        emptyEmail: false, emptyMessage: false,  
        helpName: "", helpEmail: "", helpMessage: ""
};
```

Single lines or multiple lines is ok, but it has to be a single assignment.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it

Comment: Nice! Happy to help